# Image flip and image filter android

Tags: android, image, filter, bitmap, flip

**I am trying to image flip and image filter But I have a problem with that When I put a filter on the image then when I flip the image the filter is removed**

```
public void Flipimg(View v1){
    img1.setImageBitmap(fliph(scaledBitmap));
    }
    public  Bitmap fliph(Bitmap bms){
    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.setScale(-1, 1);
    Bitmap bit1=Bitmap.createBitmap( bms, 0, 0, bms.getWidth(), bms.getHeight(), mat, true);
    return bit;         
public void Filterimg(View v2){
    img1.setImageBitmap(applyGreyscaleEffect(scaledBitmap));
    }
    public Bitmap applyGreyscaleEffect(Bitmap src) {
    final double GS_RED = 0.299;
    final double GS_GREEN = 0.587;
    final double GS_BLUE = 0.114;
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), src.getConfig());
    int A, R, G, B;
    int pixel;
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
    A = Color.alpha(pixel);
    R = Color.red(pixel);
    G = Color.green(pixel);
    B = Color.blue(pixel);
    R = G = B = (int) (GS_RED * R + GS_GREEN * G + GS_BLUE * B);
    bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));}
    }
    return bmOut;
```

[looking images THIS image flip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4NsK.jpg)

[THIS image apply filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TJuX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to apply effects sequentially, get current bitmap on the ImageView via BitmapDrawable.

```
public void Flipimg(View v1)
{
    //img1.setImageBitmap(fliph(scaledBitmap));
    Bitmap currentBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) img1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    img1.setImageBitmap(fliph(currentBitmap));
}


public void Filterimg(View v2)
{
    //img1.setImageBitmap(applyGreyscaleEffect(scaledBitmap));
    Bitmap currentBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) img1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    img1.setImageBitmap(applyGreyscaleEffect(currentBitmap));
}
```